# "Reverse" remittance - regularly moving money from Japan to Germany?

Tags: germany, money-transfer, japan

I am in the weird situation of being kind of a reverse expat. I used to work in Japan for quite a while, but have moved back to my home country of Germany. I continue to work for Japanese clients though, who pay me in Yen on my Japanese bank account. So I need a way to move this money over to Germany on a (semi) regular basis.

Regular foreign bank transfers are both pretty expensive and work intensive (virtually nothing you can do online). Over time I've worked out a system with the most cost-efficient bank I could find, but it still involves somebody having to go to the bank in person for me.

Does anyone have any tips how this could be made easier and/or cheaper?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [TransferWise](https://transferwise.com/) is the best service for sending money out of Japan recently. They have a modern web interface and the [rates are very reasonable](https://transferwise.com/pricing/jpy-to-eur). I've used them myself to send money to the UK and the process was very smooth.

Check out [RetireJapan's review](http://www.retirejapan.info/blog/transferwise-revisited):

> 1. The website is in English, it's simple and easy to use, and everything can be done online easily.
> 2. The fee is low and the exchange rate is as good as you are going to get (they use the interbank rate).
> 3. Setting up new beneficiaries can be done online in minutes, and the site remembers information from previous transfers so sending money to the same person takes seconds to set up.

Comment: "Rates are very reasonable" == 0.55% + 100¥ (plus any charges your Japanese bank makes to change the transfer the money to Transferwise).

Comment: Quoting the rate here isn't going to stay up to date very long. I added a link to their fee calculator in the answer.

Comment: The charge rate is *pretty* stable, and in my experience have only gone down.

Comment: After quite some time of experimenting, I'll accept this as the best solution for the time being. With the insanely restrictive new laws about transferring money abroad, this is by far the least complex solution to date I believe.

Answer (score 11):

I have a couple of suggestions:

- In the past, I had a simple savings account with Shinsei bank. When overseas I
  could withdraw the money from most ATMs using a simple debit card. This method was 
  easy (probably the easiest way you will get), but you would need to determine how cost effective it is. From memory I believe it was ok.
- Another option would be to transfer money via paypal. I'm not sure if this will work as Japan's PayPal has a lot of restrictions not imposed on accounts of other countries. In theory, you could create a PayPal account in Japan and an account in Germany. Then transfer money from one account to the other ( you should be able to do all of this online). If you wanted to reverse the flow of money from Germany to Japan then it wouldn't work. Personal PayPal accounts in Japan are not able to receive donations or something to that effect.
- My next suggestion was going to be to use Lloyds bank, but apparently
  their remittance service [has been taken over by Shinsei bank](http://www.japantoday.com/category/business/view/shinsei-bank-to-begin-overseas-remittance-service). I have no experience using the Shinsei remittance service, but you can find more information about it [here](http://www.goremit.jp/).

Comment: Thank you. I'l have to look into that Shinsei offering and see whether that's better than my system now. One of the main points really is the offered exchange rate, since that's currently in the dumps and having the bank take any more of it almost makes it not worthwhile at all... :)

Comment: ATM fees and losses due to exchange-rate are sure to be a lot less than wire transfer fees.

Comment: [Shinsei Bank Charges no Fee](http://faq.shinseibank.com/faq_detail.html?page=1&category=135&id=1514) and the exchange rate is 4% worse than the posted exchange rate at the time. Local ATMs may take an additional fee. English [here](http://www.shinseibank.com/english/e_speakers/faq_ic_a2.html)

Comment: Note that Shinsei are [discontinuing their overseas ATM access for their default cash cards](https://web.archive.org/web/20181010105525/http://www.shinseibank.com/info/news180606_atm_kaigai_e.html).

Answer (score 11):

As stated by [moomoochoo](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/1198/667), [Shinsei Bank](http://www.shinseibank.com/english/) is very handy for remittances overseas, so if you still have residence (for instance, you worked there and have permanent residency and have a valid address you can use to register for the bank account), then I strongly suggest you open an account during your next visit as soon as possible (opening an account needs to be done at a branch, but is very quick and easy compared to most other banks in Japan and should take under 30 minutes).

If you are no longer a resident of Japan, you are stuck with your current bank. [Non-residents cannot open new accounts in Japan](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/honyaku/dLwOWx0M264).

As a Shinsei Bank customer, you have two options:

1. ATM withdrawals (best for transfers <50k JPY)
2. Remittances (best for transfers >50k JPY)

### ATM Withdrawals

Shinsei Bank's cash card is usable [on any ATM in the PLUS network](http://www.shinseibank.com/english/e_speakers/faq_ic_a2.html) (very common in both the US and Europe). There is no fixed fee to do this, but there is a 4% fee charged over and above the [VISA international rate](http://usa.visa.com/personal/card-benefits/travel/exchange-rate-calculator-results.jsp).

To give an example, the current [EUR to JPY exchange rate](https://www.google.co.jp/#q=EUR%20to%20JPY) is 141.64. Using the VISA calculator with the 4% fee, that means you would be paying 147.80 JPY/EUR. If you are transferring 50,000 JPY, that means you get 338 EUR instead of 353 EUR, for a total fee of 15 EUR (~4.2% of the total).

This is convenient, and scales to small withdrawals easily as there is no fixed fee, but will be very expensive if you withdraw larger sums (the daily cash withdrawal limit from a foreign ATM is 100,000 JPY).

### Remittance

Shinsei Bank allows internet remittances with [GoRemit](http://www.goremit.jp/individuals/service/en). This [gives a better rate](https://www.goremit.jp/exchange/en), but has a 2,000 yen fixed fee that is added on. To give an idea of what this would look like, the exchange rate is 143.20 JPY/EUR (compared to the actual rate of 141.64). If you sent 100,000 JPY, this would mean you would get 684.36 EUR/JPY instead of the 706.02 EUR (~22 EUR, ~3.1%), which is better than the ATM withdrawal for 100,000, but will become a worse deal the smaller the withdrawal amount.

As you increase the transfer amount, the fee becomes smaller and smaller. ~5% at 50k, ~3% at 100k, ~2% at 200k, ~1.5% at 500k, etc.

Comment: Note that Shinsei are [discontinuing their overseas ATM access for their default cash cards](https://web.archive.org/web/20181010105525/http://www.shinseibank.com/info/news180606_atm_kaigai_e.html).

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, here's my current approach documented for posterity. I'm using [Money Partners](http://www.moneypartners.co.jp) to do the actual currency exchange, which gives me a pretty good rate which I'm in full control of (you can follow the rate and exchange the minute it's good). I'm then transferring the money to a foreign currency account at [Mizuho](http://www.mizuhobank.co.jp), and from there I'm wiring it to my account abroad. I also have the option to get the exchanged money in cash directly from Money Partners, should I feel like carrying a bundle with me.

This approach only costs relatively low flat fees for both transfers (Money Partners to Mizuho and Mizuho to abroad), in total something like ¥8,000 I believe. For wiring larger amounts this is pretty good, especially since I'm losing very little on the exchange rate compared to traditional banks. However, the procedure for wiring money abroad through Mizuho is pretty bureaucratic and involves a number of phone calls and paper work to be sent back and forth and/or an appearance in person.

Answer (score 3):

You should look into Bitcoin. Buy Bitcoin on an exchange like Kraken in Japan, and sell it in Germany. It should easily beat the often 10+% fees for remittances from Japan. Checkout reddit.com/r/bitcoin and ask them for help if you don't understand it.

Comment: This was probably not true in 2015 then but it definitely isn't now. There are fees for trading bitcoin to and from the exchange and between fiat currencies. There is also considerable risk that the value of bitcoin could change significantly during the process. Bitcoin exchanges are also much less regulated than pure fiat currency exchanges and have been hacked and lost their customers' funds. I'd stick to traditional methods unless you've got spare cash to play with (I actually like Bitcoin but I don't think it's a practical exchange mechanism at the moment).

Comment: If you go this option, don't limit yourself to bitcoin. There are a lot of different cryptocurrencies that could and probably should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

Brastel offers a decent exchange service. Become a free member of Brastel, you get a login where you can add your Germany Bank account details. For every Germany account you add, a dummy Japan bank account will be generated. Now you can transfer your money from Japan account to the dummy respective account, Brastel will transfer from your dummy account to respective Germany account. They also offer a JP transfer in ATMs.

[See here to know in detail.](http://brastelremit.jp/eng/howitworks)

[You can check the rates here](https://brastelremit.jp/eng/rates)

[Transaction fees here](http://brastelremit.jp/eng/fees)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I find the easiest option (and definitely a price-competitive one!) to have a credit card linked to my Japanese account and use that in Europe to withdraw cash. In my case, my German bank allows deposits using the same ATMs, so I would withdraw €500 with the Japanese credit card and immediately redeposit €400 onto my German account. Sadly, my credit card is limited to withdrawing ¥100,000 until the next billing period which means I can only transfer on average around €450 per month.

Be sure to have your credit card *not* set to revolving payments as those will invoke extra interest on your credit.

Comment: Yes, that's my worst-case fallback, but you get quite a bad exchange rate from that and lose quite a lot of money for nothing. *And* you have that limit. I'm really happy with [TransferWise](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/14091/818) at the moment; they're relatively cheap (though not free) and transfers happen almost immediately.

Comment: @deceze I just checked my last withdrawal on my credit card’s app and compared it to the historic exchange rates of that day. I paid a whopping ¥105 more on a €400 withdrawal compared to the most favourable exchange rate that existed on that day. Compared to the average rate, I lost ¥50. (Admittedly, there was the typical 1.5 % credit card usage charge to consider which is more than TransferWise’s approximately 0.75 %.) If anything, I lost on the fee, not the rate.

Comment: Then you happen to have a very favourable card, usually they're not that good. Can you disclose what card it is?

Comment: @deceze Rakuten card.

Comment: Do check the exchange rates -- Transferwise uses middle rate not the usual sell rate.

Comment: Transferwise just launched a card too.